# What is wrong with this expression on the code?

Tags: c, floating-point

I have written this piece of code in my computer and the result is 7 instead of 8 (the correct result ... I think).

I don't know why... Can somebody help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int num;
  num = (68/10.0 - 68/10)*10;
  printf("the result %d", num);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because of floating point arithmatic. 68/10.0 doesn't equal 0.8, but equals 0.7999999999999998, which rounds to 7 when multiplied by 10.

Comment: Read the C FAQ, the floating point section.

Answer (score 0):

`double` typically represents *exactly* about 2<sup>64</sup> different numbers. `68/10.0` is not one of them,

As a [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), `68/10.0` is about 
`6.7999999999999998223643161...`, the closest value to 6.8 that is a multiple of a [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational). [@ AntonH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2261424/antonh)

`68/10` is an integer division with a quotient of 6.

`(68/10.0 - 68/10)*10` is thus about `7.9999999999999982236431606...`

Assigning that to an `int` is 7 not 8 as the fraction is discarded even though it is *very close* to 8.

When converting a floating point value consider round to the the closest, rather than truncating.

```
num = lround((68/10.0 - 68/10)*10);
```